# How to forward file from request to other app in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I need to send all data from form in Django to other application (through REST API).
The problem is with forwarding InMemoryUploadedFile (which i'm catching it from request).
I have big problem with build new request: content of the file is always empty (uploaded file is empty).
I had to create my own request.body builder method (encode_multipart_formdata) cus requests, i don't know why, can't do this properly. Inside this function when i call: tmpfile.read()
i got empty string, but when I'm trying do this earlier for ex. in addContent() everything is ok..

**views.py**

```py
def addContent(request):
if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
    form = ContentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        data = restApiController.addContent(request.POST, request.FILES)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/content')  # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = ContentForm  # An unbound form
return render(request, 'content/addNew.html', {'form': form, })
```

**restApiController.py**

```py
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def addContent(requestPOST, requestFILE):
   content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(requestPOST, requestFILE)
   h = {'Content-Type': content_type}
   r = requests.post(settings.CONTENTS_URL, auth=('user', 'pass'), headers=h, data=body)

def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
   boundary = 'ARCFormBoundaryovmtr0efdw019k9'
   CRLF = '\r\n'
   L = []
 for (key, value) in fields.iteritems():
    L.append('--' + boundary)
    L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
    L.append('')
    L.append(value)
 for (key, value) in files.iteritems():
    L.append('--' + boundary)
    L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % ('contentFile', files['contentFile']._name))
    L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(files['contentFile']._name))
    L.append('')
    L.append(files['contentFile'].read())
   L.append('--' + boundary + '--')
   L.append('')
   #body = CRLF.join(L) INSTEAD DO THIS:
   s = BytesIO()
   for element in L:
     s.write(str(element))
     s.write(CRLF)
   body = s.getvalue()
content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % boundary
return content_type, body
```

body content:

```
-----------------------------11286521771531197711838573892 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name" 
test 
-----------------------------11286521771531197711838573892 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="language" 
eng 
-----------------------------11286521771531197711838573892 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contentFile"; filename="chaos_handdrums.wav" 
Content-Type: audio/x-wav
-----------------------------11286521771531197711838573892 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type" 
stream 
-----------------------------11286521771531197711838573892--
```

in body context should be also context of binary file, but isn't..

Comment: RESOLVED:

Founded solution on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/

instead: body = CRLF.join(L) 
Do this:    s = BytesIO() for element in L:
         s.write(str(element))
         s.write(CRLF) body = s.getvalue()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just use `requests.post(url, data=[('name', 'test'), ('language', 'eng'), ('type', 'stream')], files={'chaos_handdrums.wav': <file-like-object>})` and requests will do the multipart conversion for you.